The signature of each column of the chart in WinForms
I need to make a graph with statistics for each month. But the columns are not signed. Only in the middle of the chart is the first month.
enter image description here
var valuesAsArray = (MonthEnum[])System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(MonthEnum));
int[] pointsArray = { 50, 100, 17, 5, 30, 41, 42, 9, 88, 14, 37, 50 };

for (int i = 0; i < valuesAsArray.Length; i++)
{
    Series series = chart1.Series.Add(valuesAsArray[i].ToString());
    series.Points.AddXY(valuesAsArray[i].ToString(), pointsArray[i]);
    series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Bar;
    series.Points[0].Label = pointsArray[i].ToString();
    series.CustomProperties = "PointWidth=2";
}

